# gc.log file error when running cassandra

Tags: cassandra

In order to install Cassandra,  I've done the following:
1. Downloaded the TAR file. 
2. Extracted the file. 
3. Set the path for data and commitlog directories in the yaml file.

Now when I run Cassandra,  I'm getting the following error:
"Java HotSpot (TM)  64-Bit Server VM warning: Cannot open file. /..logs/gc.log due to No such file or directory"

What's causing this problem? Do I need to do something else before running it.

OS: RHEL 6.5
Cassandra version: 3.11.1

Comment: I've created  bug for it: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-14142 & provided a fix

Comment: Adding more info as I believe this breaks `homebrew` silently as well. https://gist.github.com/jpalala/ab3c33dd9ee5a6efbdae#gistcomment-1989750

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Cassandra logs all gcs in a log file called gc.log. The path of this file is defined in cassandra-env.sh:

```
#GC log path has to be defined here because it needs to access CASSANDRA_HOME
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Xloggc:${CASSANDRA_HOME}/logs/gc.log"
```

Make sure you have a folder in your cassandra folder called logs and that whatever user you're running cassandra with has write permisssions to this folder.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked for me:
${CASSANDRA_HOME} is set in /home/richard/.bashrc but with Cassandra you have a Cassandra user so ${CASSANDRA_HOME} has to be put in that Cassandra users /home/cassandra/.bashrc as well. My Cassandra is in

`/usr/local/cassandra/apache-cassandra-3.11.3`

so to add logs I did a `sudo mkdir logs`. Then -ls -la showed root root so I did a

`sudo chwon cassandra:cassandra logs`

Do a cd .. to go up one directory and issue ls -la. I did a chown on each level above. I did it back to /usr/local which may be one to far and cause issues later but it looked low risk. Then I changed .bashrc in home and Cassandra from -Xloggc to -Xlog:gc as requried by the V9 and later Java

```
From JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Xloggc:${CASSANDRA_HOME}/logs/gc.log"
To   JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Xlog:gc:${CASSANDRA_HOME}/logs/gc.log"
```

I switch to the Cassandra user and started Cassandra successfully

```
sudo - cassandra
```

I have

```
export cassandra=/usr/local/cassandra/apache-cassandra-3.11.3/bin/cassandra
```

in .bashrc so when I enter $cassandra my first line echoed:

```
in /usr/local/cassandra/apache-cassandra-3.11.3/conf/casandra-env.sh
```

and my last line was

```
StorageService.java:2289 - Node localhost/127.0.0.1 state jump to NORMAL
```

If you are still having problems stick with it.

```
richard@sony:~$ sudo updatedb
richard@sony:~$ locate .bashrc
/home/richard/.bashrc
/home/cassandra/.bashrc

richard@sony:/usr/local/cassandra/apache-cassandra-3.11.3/logs$ ls -la
total 1636
drwxr-xr-x  2 cassandra cassandra    4096 Sep 30 10:30 .
drwxrwxr-x 12 cassandra cassandra    4096 Sep 30 10:17 ..
-rw-rw-r--  1 cassandra cassandra 1569961 Sep 30 11:31 debug.log
-rw-rw-r--  1 cassandra cassandra    1116 Sep 30 11:46 gc.log
-rw-rw-r--  1 cassandra cassandra     945 Sep 30 10:18 gc.log.0
-rw-rw-r--  1 cassandra cassandra   85584 Sep 30 11:31 system.log
```

Answer (score 0):

I am a windows user and I was facing a similar problem. I tried to resolve it by trying different things. Although I forgot one simple step, to run the command prompt as administrator. Once I ran as administrator, my problem was solved.